# ExecuteNonQuery() always returning -1

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, executenonquery, executescalar

I'm creating a login application with C# and SQL Server.

What my program does: it looks if the given username and password can be found in the database.

If it can be found, `ExecuteNonQuery()` should return 1 (1 row found).

If the combination doesn't exist, `ExecuteNonQuery()` should return something else.

But in my case, whenever I use a good or wrong combination, it always returns -1... how do I fix this?

I know, there are some existing posts for the same question, but it's still not fixed...

Also, what is the difference between `ExecuteNonQuery()` & `ExecuteScalar()`?

This is the query being sent:

```
private void btn_loginvolgende_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam = Convert.ToString(tb_gebruikersnaamlogin.Text);
    gebruiker.Wachtwoord = Convert.ToString(tb_wachtwoordlogin.Text);
    gebruiker.Achternaam = "a";
    gebruiker.Geslacht = "a";
    gebruiker.Geslacht = "a";
    gebruiker.Huidiggewicht = 1;
    gebruiker.Streefgewicht = 1;
    gebruiker.Leeftijd = 1;
    gebruiker.Naam = "a";

    db.QueryToDatabase("Select count (*) from Gebruiker where Wachtwoord = @Wachtwoord AND Gebruikersnaam = @Gebruikersnaam;", gebruiker);
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    if (db.Success == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login gegevens kloppen niet!");
    }
    else if (db.Success == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("U bent met succes ingelogd");
    }
}
```

and this is my class:

```
public void QueryToDatabase(string commandText, Gebruikerklasse gebruiker)
{
    // nieuwe connectie maken
    // ontvangt de query vanuit 'buttonclick' en voert hem hier uit
    // als ExecuteNonQuery niet kan worden uitgevoerd is er iets fout gegaan. D.m.v een bool moet hij dan een bericht tonen
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", gebruiker.Naam);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Achternaam", gebruiker.Achternaam);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leeftijd", gebruiker.Leeftijd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Geslacht", gebruiker.Geslacht);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Huidiggewicht", gebruiker.Huidiggewicht);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Streefgewicht", gebruiker.Streefgewicht);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruikersnaam", gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wachtwoord", gebruiker.Wachtwoord);

        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (a == 1)
        {
            Success = true;
        }
        else if (a == -1)
        {
            Success = false;
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are running a SELECT query. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of affected rows when you run an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE. If you want to kwow if you have a record then use ExecuteReader and the check if the returned object HasRows

Comment: from msdn, For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: Looking better, that query should be run by ExecuteScalar because you have a single row with a single column as result

Comment: I am using the same method for a sign up. I need executenonquery for that one. But do u suggest me to make another method for login? So I can use ExecuteReader?

Comment: It seems that you want a single method to do every possible task against a database. This is practically impossible. A better approach is to have specific methods in your class that do the interaction with a database.

Comment: Typo alerts: it's a **query** (just one "r" is **quite** enough!), but on the other hand, it's **Success** (with **two** `s` at the end) - and this applies to *multiple* of your questions recently ....

Comment: the answer is in the StoredProcedure itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want a single method to do every possible task against a database. This is practically impossible. A better approach is to have specific methods in your class that do the interaction with a database

For example you could change your `Gebruikerklasse` and add a method called `Exists` where you can fine tune the interaction for the specific task. No need to create a lot of parameters when you need only two. Use the more performant ExecuteScalar (and correct) call to get your information back from the storage, etc....

```
public class Gebruikerklasse 
{
    ....
    public bool Exists()
    {
        string commandText = @"Select count (*) from Gebruiker 
                              where Wachtwoord = @Wachtwoord AND 
                             Gebruikersnaam = @Gebruikersnaam;", 
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBClass.GetConnectionString()))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruikersnaam", gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wachtwoord", gebruiker.Wachtwoord);
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return (a > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This should be only a first step in creating an OOP approach to your tasks. Next is to learn how to separate your model from your database code.

Side note: forcing a count of the table just to discover if an entry exists or not is a waste. There is a specific SQL statement that helps a lot here.
Search for IF EXISTS and read this article
[Exists vs Count The battle never ends](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx)

Comment: var a = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (a > 0)
                {
                    Succes = true;
                }


                else 
                {
                    Succes = false;
                }
It worked! Thanks! It's kinda awkward to ask these 'stupid' questions here...

Comment: Well it is the same thing, but because the code above is in a different class probably there is no property Success.

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions has been answered. But I would like to add some additional information for you:

ExecuteNonQuery - runs a query and returns the affected rows.

ExecuteScalar - runs a query and returns the value of the first column of the first row.

ExecuteReader - runs a query and returns a SqlDataReader; that can be used to read the requested database records

I recently wrote a tutorial on this as well, including "memory management". Please see: http://jeroenstevens.blogspot.ca/2017/02/how-to-connect-netc-to-sql-database.html